# "No more data to read from socket" error while deleting record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sockets

I have implemented function based unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "UK_ACCOUNT_TYPE" ON "ACCOUNT" (
    CASE "ACTIVE"
      WHEN '1'
      THEN "FK_PARTNERID"
      ELSE NULL
    END,

    CASE "ACTIVE"
      WHEN '1'
      THEN "TYPE"
      ELSE NULL
    END
);
```

[Note: FK_PARTNERID is foreign key. Basically we want to keep only 1 record active for specific type of user(FK_PARTNERID) and specific type of account(TYPE).]

After that, if I try to delete a record from this table, it disconnects from server and gives such error: "No more data to read from socket. Commit failed."

I have to reconnect the client to server.
This issue occurs when I try to delete record from coding also.

Insert/Update/Select statements work normally.

If I drop this index, deletion works fine.

Oracle server version is 11g (11.2.0.3)

Here is log showing in SQL Developer:
[image]

Here is listener alert log: (from path: /opt/oracle/product/diag/tnslsnr/dev-vm/listener/alert)

```
<msg time='2013-10-04T14:43:04.079+00:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='dev-vm'
 host_addr='192.168.56.101'>
 <txt>04-OCT-2013 14:43:04 * service_update * ORCL * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2013-10-04T14:43:20.365+00:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='dev-vm'
 host_addr='192.168.56.101'>
 <txt>04-OCT-2013 14:43:20 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=glassfish))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=45602)) * establish * orcl * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2013-10-04T14:44:01.112+00:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='dev-vm'
 host_addr='192.168.56.101'>
 <txt>04-OCT-2013 14:44:01 * service_update * ORCL * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2013-10-04T14:44:04.115+00:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='dev-vm'
 host_addr='192.168.56.101'>
 <txt>04-OCT-2013 14:44:04 * service_update * ORCL * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2013-10-04T14:44:34.128+00:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='dev-vm'
 host_addr='192.168.56.101'>
 <txt>04-OCT-2013 14:44:34 * service_update * ORCL * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Alert log:

```
Mon Oct 07 07:38:12 2013
Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
Mon Oct 07 13:30:09 2013
Exception [type: SIGSEGV, Address not mapped to object] [ADDR:0x6] [PC:0x8A7767C, evakdustoopn()+76] [flags: 0x0, count: 1]
Errors in file /opt/oracle/product/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/trace/ORCL_ora_12500.trc  (incident=104683):
ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [evakdustoopn()+76] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x6] [PC:0x8A7767C] [Address not mapped to object] []
Incident details in: /opt/oracle/product/diag/rdbms/orcl/ORCL/incident/incdir_104683/ORCL_ora_12500_i104683.trc
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Mon Oct 07 13:30:12 2013
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20131007133012], requested by (instance=1, osid=12500), summary=[incident=104683].
Mon Oct 07 13:30:13 2013
Sweep [inc][104683]: completed
Sweep [inc2][104683]: completed
```

Comment: Do you have a corresponding error in the server's alert log? And are there triggers on the table, particularly on delete?

Comment: Please check for the log(attached image) I get in SQL developer.

There are no triggers in this table.

Comment: I don't think the SQL Developer log is showing you anything useful. I meant the server-side alert log; if you don't have access to that you might have to get your DBA to check it. It looks like the session is dying on the server end so any diagnostics will have to come from the server too (including inside the DB, but stuff your client won't ave been aware of).

Comment: Ok, I have asked to DBA for log. I will be back once I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexPoole, I have added Oracle listener alert log in description. Can you please check with that? Honestly, I don't understand the log and not sure you asked for this or anything else.

Comment: The listener just hands off the connection to the database process; this is showing a successful connection (the second message, with `establish`). From your description is sounds like the database process experiences an error - possibly an ORA-00600 - which terminates it and this stops sending data to the client, which leads to the message you see. It's the *database* alert log that might hold a clue, not the listener; sorry, probably should have been clearer, but your DBA should know that and be able to find and interpret the relevant log entry, if there is one.

Comment: There is a bug, 13649540, which looks like it *might* be similar to what you're seeing. Your DBA can compare the alert log (ORA-00600 and ORA-07445) details to see if it is an exact match, and may beed to raise an SR with Oracle. There may be a patch, or it may be fixed in 11.2.0.4, according to note 1490515.1. It could be something else though.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thank you very much for your help. I have found alert log and updated question description with that. You are right, there is ORA-07445 but not ORA-00600. Can you please take a look at log and suggest what went gone wrong?

Comment: `ORA-7445 [EVAKDUSTOOPN()+76] ` is exactly what bug 14398795 refers to. Your DBA needs to look at this, and decide whether/how to patch. There doesn't seem to be a workaround.

Comment: Can you please share oracle bug url?

Comment: You need to log into support.oracle.com and search for it. You need a customer support identifier. Your DBA will hopefully already have access and be able to see the bug and get the patch, so there might not be much point you looking - seems this is really down to your DBA to investigate and sort out.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Thank you very much Alex for your support and help. If you add your summary as an answer, I would glad to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORA-03113` error indicates that the server process that was handling your update died unexpectedly. There can be many reasons for that, and the server alert log has shown the `ORA-07445` that the back-end process got in this case.

Searching the Oracle support site reveals a bug, 13649540, which seems to match what you're seeing. I'm not allowed to reproduce material from that site here, so you or your DBA, or someone with access and a customer support identifier, will need to investigate further.

You might be able to get a patch for your platform, but there doesn't seem to be a workaround, so I don't think you'll be able to fix this in code. Raising a service request with Oracle might lead to some options that aren't published on their support site though. The alert log has some information to help your DBA package and report the incident.

Ultimately it's something your DBA will need to look at and deal with. There doesn't seem to be anything you can do about it as a developer.